# 403 InvalidSignatureException:Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Flutter and aws_lex_runtime_api

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-lex

I'm working on a flutter project to build a voice bot with flutter and AWS LEX. I use `aws_lex_runtime_api` package.

When I try to send a text message to AWS LEX via `postText(botAlias: "alias",botName: "botname",inputText: _text, userId: "userId");`, it work well and I receive response.

But in my case, I want to send a voice to LEx to use voice interaction instead of text interaction.

First, when I send my first request

```
postContent(
    botAlias: "botAlias",
    botName: "botname",
    contentType: "audio/x-l16; sample-rate=16000; channel-count=1",
    inputStream: Uint8List.fromList("Je souhaiterais commander des fleurs".codeUnits),
    userId: "userId");
```

I received this error: `Unhandled Exception: BadRequestException BadRequestException: Invalid Request: The header x-amz-content-sha256 must be set to the literal string UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD.`

To figure out, I add this line in lex_runtime_code. `headers['x-amz-content-sha256'] = "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD";`

After that, I send the request again and obtain these errors:

```
E/flutter (14630): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 403 InvalidSignatureException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
E/flutter (14630): #0      throwException (package:shared_aws_api/src/protocol/shared.dart:324:3)
E/flutter (14630): #1      RestJsonProtocol.sendRaw (package:shared_aws_api/src/protocol/rest-json.dart:78:7)
E/flutter (14630): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14630): #2      LexRuntimeService.postContent (package:aws_lex_runtime_api/runtime.lex-2016-11-28.dart:475:22)
E/flutter (14630): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14630): #3      _SpeechScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:kiwi/pages/speechscreen.dart:87:46)
E/flutter (14630): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14630):
```

I make much research to solve this issue, for now, two weeks but don't find a solution. Can anyone have an idea on how to solve this?